# Can't send email via codeinginter using cpanel email account

Tags: codeigniter, email, cpanel

I have problem when sending email from my server to somebody account
i mean that i need to send email from 
**myemail@mydomain.com** to any another account Whether **Live, hotmail or gmail** etc.
of course that from `PHP script`

I have been created email account from my `CPanel`, and i tried to send email by this code.

```
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = "mail.mydomain.com";
$config['smtp_user'] = "myemail@mydomain.com";
$config['smtp_pass'] = "password";
$config['smtp_port'] = "25";

$this->load->library('email',$config);

$this->email->from("myemail@mydomain.com", 'test');

$this->email->to("actualemail@live.com"); // the user email

$this->email->subject("hello");

$this->email->message("test test test");

if (!$this->email->send()) {
    echo "error";
    //$this->email->print_debugger();
    exit;
}
//$this->email->print_debugger();
//exit;
echo "success";
```

**Note that** i'm using codeigniter framework.
The strange is there is no any problem in sending email , i get success message, but when i go to my receive email account i not found
any email. what to do, I'm boring form a lot of attempts :( .

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$to = 'you@gmail.com';
$subject = 'my subject';
$msg = 'Hi..........';
$headers = "From: info@domain.com\r\nReply-To: info@domain.com";
$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $msg, $headers );
echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed";
```

It directly takes details from your server & sends mail.
This works fine on my site.

Comment: Thank you for your helping

I apply your code and i get the "Mail sent" message.
But i entered to my account and no any email received! what is the problem ?

Comment: Check your spam Folder. May be you can get it there.

Comment: Unfortunately, NO there is not any trace for email, Although i'm sure from email addresses 100% :(